# How can I create a custom Firebase new user e-mail verification flow into my Angular application?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am working on an Angular application hosted on Firebase and using Firebase Authentication service in order to handle user registration. When a user sign up in the application I send an e-mail for e-mail confirmation, I do this by this code:

```
userCreated.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
    console.log("User verification e-mail sent to: ", userCreated.email);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("ERROR SENDING USER VERIFICATION E-MAIL !!! THE USER E-MAIL HAVE TO BE VERIFIED MANUALLY BY THE ADMIN");
    alert("ERROR SENDING USER VERIFICATION E-MAIL !!! THE USER E-MAIL HAVE TO BE VERIFIED MANUALLY BY THE ADMIN");
});
```

Ok the problem is that I have to implement some further extra logic to my user verification (what happens when the user click on the link inside the e-mail).

I found this article about **custom-email-handler**: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

But I have some doubt about how exactly integrate it into my Angular project. From what I can undestand (but I am absolutly not sure of this so please give me some hints) it works in this way:

- I have to create a custom verification e-mail template containing a custom verification link (this time pointing to a specific Angular component related to the specific route into my Angular application)
- In this component I can handle the **verifyEmail** mode implementing this method adding here my extra custom logic:

  function handleVerifyEmail(auth, actionCode, continueUrl, lang) {
  // Localize the UI to the selected language as determined by the lang
  // parameter.
  // Try to apply the email verification code.
  auth.applyActionCode(actionCode).then(function(resp) {
  // Email address has been verified.

  ```
   // TODO: Display a confirmation message to the user.
   // You could also provide the user with a link back to the app.

   // TODO: If a continue URL is available, display a button which on
   // click redirects the user back to the app via continueUrl with
   // additional state determined from that URL's parameters.
  ```

  }).catch(function(error) {
  // Code is invalid or expired. Ask the user to verify their email address
  // again.
  });
  }

I am not sure if I have to do inside a component of my Angular application or in a Firebase cloud function or where else.

Can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 1):

> I have to create a custom verification e-mail template containing a
> custom verification link (this time pointing to a specific Angular
> component related to the specific route into my Angular application)

Yes, you can customize the Firebase template through the Firebase console, in order to point the link to a page that you implement in your Angular web app. Firebase appends the set of query string parameters detailed in the doc.

Note that you could also generate the email through a Cloud Function through the `generateEmailVerificationLink()` method of the Admin SDK.

---

Then, in the corresponding page of your web app, you need to

1. Extract the query string parameters from the URL

The [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) gives one of the possible solution with the `getParameterByName()` method

```
  // Get the action to complete.
  var mode = getParameterByName('mode');
  // Get the one-time code from the query parameter.
  var actionCode = getParameterByName('oobCode');
  // (Optional) Get the continue URL from the query parameter if available.
  var continueUrl = getParameterByName('continueUrl');
  // (Optional) Get the language code if available.
  var lang = getParameterByName('lang') || 'en';
```

2. Use the value of the `actionCode` to call the [`applyActionCode()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#applyactioncode) method, which is the key action in this process: when the promise returned by this method is fulfilled, the email is verified. You can then implement the extra business
   logic that you want.

It is important to note that this happens in the front-end (i.e. inside a component of your Angular application), so if the extra custom business logic needs to be done in the back-end (e.g. adding a Custom Claim), you need to call a Cloud Function. If your custom business logic can be done from the front-end (e.g. update a Firestore document), just do it from this page, after having verified the email, i.e. in the `then()` block, as shown below:

```
auth.applyActionCode(actionCode).then(function(resp) {
    // Email address has been verified.
    
    // Implement your custom logic here

  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Code is invalid or expired. Ask the user to verify their email address
    // again.
  });
```

Note that since this code is implemented via a component of your Angular application, the user is most probably already signed in, since there are great chances that he previously created his account via the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method, which signs him into your application.